# How to execute/schedule php script on Ubuntu in every 1 minute : without cron job?

Tags: php

I want to execute one script on daily basis. for that i have to use scheduling concept. But I don`t know Without cron-job service its is possible to execute on Ubuntu System.

I found the way where we can create `.sh` file, but how it will process or how the actual execution will happen that I don`t know. Can any one help me?

Thank you.

Comment: In which programming language do you write code?

Comment: In php laguage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1_st.php

```
<?php
//some code
?>
```

2_nd.php

```
<?php
shell_exec(sh_script.sh);    
?>
```

sh_script.sh

```
/usr/bin/bash
while true; do 
    1_st.php &
    sleep 60
done
```

**Note:** do not forget write correct files path

Comment: /usr/bin/bash
while true; do 
    1_st.php &
    sleep 60
done             : in this 1_st.php file path not found error occur.. which path i have to mention ? localhost or /var/www/html/project/.....?

Comment: /var/www/html/project/.....

Answer (score 1):

```
while true; do 
    /path/to/executable_file &
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: In which file i want to mention this code? In the php file?

Comment: shell scripting (.sh)

Comment: this has great potential for damaging the server